# Only pass additional parameters if they are not empty

Tags: c#, parameters

In one of our projects we have something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry;
if (user == "" && password == "")
    directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
else
    directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, password);
```

I want to know if there is a possibility to do this as a one-line-statement. I know that the two methods aren't working the same way. However, is it possible to check the condition inside the brackets and let the compiler decide which method to take. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry =
    new DirectoryEntry(path, (user == "" && password == "") ? user, password : [nothing]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you don't use it like that?

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
if (user != "" && password != "")
{
    directoryEntry.Username = user;
    directoryEntry.Password = password;
}
```

links 
[Username](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) 
[Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.password(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: good one you only should replace your if condition `if (user != "" || password != "")`

Comment: :O my bad! didn't see that :(

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DirectoryEntry  directoryEntry = (user == "" && password == "") ? new DirectoryEntry(path) : new DirectoryEntry(path, user, password);
```

Comment: This would be a way I already thought of. I just wanted to know if it's possible to do it inside the brackets.

Answer (score -2):

This will work.

```
DirectoryEntry  directoryEntry = (user == "" && password == "") ? new DirectoryEntry(path) : new DirectoryEntry(path, user, password);
```

Comment: That's what fubo already suggested. I know I can do it like this but I wanted to know if I can do it inside the brackets.